# Doctrine 2: Cache in One-to-Many associations

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use doctrine cache from Common package, but I can't get it working with one-to-many, many-to-one accosiations. I'll explain later what I want to do.

My configuration:

```
'configuration' => array(
    'orm_default' => array(
        'metadata_cache'    => 'filesystem',
        'query_cache'       => 'filesystem',
        'result_cache'      => 'filesystem',
        'hydration_cache'   => 'filesystem',
    )
),
```

My entity

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    protected  $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="childrenId", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parentId;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parentId", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $childrenId;
}
```

My DQL

```
$result = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->select('c')
    ->from('App\Entity\Category', 'c')
    ->where('c.parentId IS NULL')
    ->orderBy('c.priority', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->setFetchMode("App\Entity\Category", "parentId", \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
    ->useResultCache(true, 900, 'categories')
    ->getResult();
```

I have **28 categories**, **15** of them have parentId.
Above query executes **29 SQL queries**, but Doctrine store in cache only **1**, So when I run again this query, it executes **28 queries**.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? missing some cache configuration? missing some methods in DQL? I would like to cache **all** queries not only one- main query.

**Edit**

I would like to use query result in loop, like this:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $categories[]['attr'] = $row->getAttribute()->getName();
    $categories[]['value'] = $row->getAttribute()->getValue();
}
```

but this way cache won't work, so currently I'm using:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
        $attributes = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()->select('c, a.name, a.value')
            ->from('App\Entity\Category', 'c')
            ->innerJoin('App\Entity\Attribute', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.id = c.attribute')
            ->where('c.id = :catId')
            ->setParameter('catId', $row['id'])
            ->getQuery()
            ->useResultCache(true, 900, $categoryName.'-attributes')
            ->getArrayResult();
}
```

But I would rather work on objects then on arrays, but I can't cuz if I use object and it has association then this association will not be cached. So ideally would be some way to cache object + ALL his associations.

Comment: Are you looking to store the query results in a cache? You can refer to the documentation for caching query results at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache

Comment: Please paste code that is using your `$result` as this query is producing only one query. Also it'd be nice if you could paste all 28 queries.

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek I edited my post. These 28 queries are in loop like in example above.

Comment: Hope this tutorial helps you. http://bhaktaraz.com.np/caching-data-in-symfony2/

Comment: The problem here isn't the cache, it's the query ;)

Comment: [Using doctrine APC caching with QueryBuilder in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ck9l/using-doctrine-apc-caching-with-query-builder-in-symfony)

Answer (score 5):

#### Association fetch-modes

The query you present only fetches "parent" `Category` entities, which get hydrated with an *uninitialized* collection for the children. When accessing that collection (by iterating over those children for example), Doctrine will load the collection, thus perform another query. It will do that for all parent categories hydrated by the first query.

Setting fetch-mode to EAGER *only* changes the moment these queries are done. Doctrine will do them right after hydrating the parent categories, it won't wait until you access the collection (like with fetch-mode LAZY). But it will still do those queries.

#### Fetch-join query

The simplest way to tell Doctrine to query and hydrate the categories with their children is to do a "fetch join" query:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->select('p', 'c') // [p]arent, [c]hild
    ->from('App\Entity\Category', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.children', 'c')
    ->where('p.parent IS NULL')
    ->orderBy('p.priority', 'ASC');

$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$query
    ->useResultCache(true, 900, 'categories')

$result = $query->getResult();
```

Note the `select()` and `leftJoin()` calls here.

You also don't need to alter the fetch-mode of the association (by calling `setFetchMode()`), because the query itself will tell Doctrine to do what you want.

The result of this is that Doctrine will perform 1 query if it isn't cached yet (or the cache is stale), or 0 queries if it is cached (and still fresh).

#### Assumptions

The property `$parentId` (in `Category`) is renamed to `$parent`. This property will contain the parent `Category` entity, or `null`, but never an id.

The property `$childrenId` is renamed to `$children`. This property will contain a collection of `Category` entities (which might be empty), but never a collection (or array) of ids, and certainly never a single id.

The query I suggest above takes these renames into account.

I'm completely ignoring the fact that right after your "edit" a new `Attribute` entity has sprung into existence. It isn't relevant to your question or this answer IMHO.

#### More levels

It looks/sounds like your Categories only use 2 levels (parents and children). When you introduce more levels (grandchildren, etc), reading this model can become very inefficient very quickly.

When going for 3 or more levels, you might want to look into the [Nested Set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). It's heavier on the writes, but highly optimized for reads.

The [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) library has support for this, and there's also a [Symfony Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql I think that `setFetchMode - EAGER` will not work for you as this will produce extra queries that will not be cached.

Why don't you load your categories with attributes?

```
$result = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c, a.name, a.value')
    ->from('App\Entity\Category', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('App\Entity\Attribute', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.id = c.attribute')
    ->where('c.parentId IS NULL')
    ->orderBy('c.priority', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->useResultCache(true, 900, 'categories')
    ->getResult();
```

And it should work as expected.